# Look for item inside list, when found, inside same item before it. (python)

Tags: python, list, insert

inside a list I'm looking for the item '-', when we find it, I want to insert '-' before it.
Should be pretty easy but I'm struggling :S

Comment: Have you found the index of the item in the list already? Do you know how to insert data into a given location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `list.insert` and `list.index` methods. `index` gives you the index of the item you're looking for, `insert` does what it says it does:

```
l = ['a', 1, '-', 2] # random list
l.insert(l.index('-'), '-')
print(l)
```

Reacting to your comment: If you have more than one occurence, it works a bit less elegantly:

```
l = ["a", 1, "-", 2, "-", 2, 5, "-"]
# get indices of '-'
idxs = [i for i, c in enumerate(l) if c == "-"]
# loop over indices and insert, account for already added items
for i, idx in enumerate(idxs):
    l.insert(idx + i, "-")
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, there are multiple occurences of that '-' item.

Comment: Are there only characters in the list?

Comment: This is part of the list
[ '9,940 RON', '-80.6 %', '9,940 RON', '-77.33 %', '-', '17', '699', 'PITESTI - ROUMASPORT', '8,650 RON', '-80.88 %', '8,650 RON']

Comment: I updated my answer. There's probably a more elegant way, but this works.